# Zend basic question - How to configure DAO to be used?

Tags: zend-framework, dao

I have this following directory structure:

auth
controllers
daos

etc..

I have this DAO working:

```
class TeamsDao extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    protected $_name = 'teams';
```

etc...

I want to add a new DAO and my question is:

After adding the file and a new class representing a new dao, do I need to tell zend that I do have a new DAO in place somewhere?

Thanks,
MEM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a question of instantiating the DAO. No special configuration needed.  Cheers.